# $\lim \sup$ of sequences of finite valued functions maybe infinite

Tags: probability-theory

I can't understand the following note from Williams Probability with Martingales.

I can't imagine a sequence of finite valued functions that has an inifinite $\lim \sup$

Could you give an example / explanation? thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For each positive integer $n,$ let $f_n:{\mathbb R} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ be the constant function whose value is $n.$ Then each $f_n$ has only finite values (a single finite value, in fact), and the limit of this sequence of functions is the constant function whose value is $+\infty.$